# C# store app webservice username not provided

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-store-apps

When I try to access a webservice I get the following error message:

> The username is not provided. Specify username in ClientCredentials.

I do make new credentials as seen in the following code:

```
public AppWebService_PortClient openConn2()
{
    BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();

    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
    BasicHttpSecurityMode sMode = binding.Security.Mode;

    EndpointAddress adress = new EndpointAddress("myURL");

    AppWebService_PortClient client = 
        new AppWebService_PortClient(binding, adress);

    client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential = 
        new System.Net.NetworkCredential("Username", "Password", "Domain");
    string userName = 
        client.ClientCredentials.Windows.ClientCredential.UserName;
    //client.ClientCredentials.Windows.AllowedImpersonationLevel 
        //= TokenImpersonationLevel.Delegation;

    return client;
}
```

if i read out the credentials as in `string userName` i get the right username. Why do i get that error?

Answer (score 1):

Looks a bit like this issue: [Setting ClientCredentials: getting "Username is not provided" error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13099225/setting-clientcredentials-getting-username-is-not-provided-error)

Which had the following "solution". Which might apply to your case.:

> Do you have security mode, clientCredentialtype configured appropriately in your configuration files? Here is a blog post that very closely matches your question. I hope this helps!
>
> http://amadotech.blogspot.com/2009/11/error-username-is-not-provided-specify.html
>
> Actually there're three causes with my application:
>
> Security mode was not appropriae.
>   Client credential type was not appropriate.
>   The call missed passing the required Username and password.

Comment: That, indeed, sounds like my error. But the blog states I should change my app.config file. I am unable to locate it in C# store apps though. So its not usefull to me :) but thanks for your reply

Comment: True, but you can set the Transport mode and CredentialType in code as well?
What I mean is, try setting the Security Mode to None. And see if that works. And work your way up from there?

Comment: If i set the security mode to none i will get an error : "The provided URI scheme 'https' is invalid; epected 'http'.\r\nParamater name:via" To solve this problem i had to put the security mode to : TransportWithMessageCredential

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use

```
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "Username";
client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "Password";
```

instead.